# Definition of Polish Topology

Tags: general-topology, definition

Let $\xi$ such that $1 \leq \xi < \omega_1$ and $f$ be of Baire class $\xi$. In [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/0000-000-00/S0002-9947-2016-06764-1/S0002-9947-2016-06764-1.pdf) (Section $5$), the author defined

$$T_{f,\xi}=\left\{ \tau^{\prime} : \tau \subset \tau^{\prime} \text{ Polish}, \tau^{\prime} \subset \sum_{\xi}^0{(\tau)}, f \in B_1(\tau^{\prime}) \right\}$$

I don't understand the meaning of Polish topology. I search online and but I couldn't find anything about it. What I found is Polish space but not polish topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that it is a topology (on the presumably fixed underlying set), that makes it a Polish space (i.e. separable and completely metrisable).